# Formatting a PC without admin rights

Tags: formatting, format, computer-architecture

I was at a flea market the other day and bought a computer. However, the computer is locked and I can't login to it. Is there a way to format the computer and install Linux on it?

It seems like the computer has been an old work computer and that there is an administrator account.

By locked I mean that the computer has an admin, and when I try to install linux from a bootable cd it does not start from that cd, saying I don't have the rights.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “locked”. Are you, perhaps, referring to a firmware password?

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could probably replace the hard drive and BIOS. This would cost some money, but hopefully less than a new computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **It seems like the computer has been an old work computer and that there is an administrator account.**

### "BIOS" passwords

Some computers intended for business use have an optional boot password that can be set in the [BIOS](http://www.pcworld.com/article/158292/Enable_BIOS_Passwords_for_Extra_Security.html).

You may be able to reset this by removing and replacing the battery on the motherboard. If in doubt obtain a user-manual for the specific model of computer or for the motherboard.

However this sort of hardware/firmware password would be requested by the computer prior to any indication of Windows booting. It isn't clear from your question if this is the case.

Note: The term BIOS is used loosely here.

### UEFI Secure Boot

You may need to disable [Secure Boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/). or install a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, which supports it.

### Microsoft Windows Administrator passwords

Normally, Windows Administrator accounts should not prevent you booting from a device like the DVD-ROM drive or a bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a Linux LiveCD (either USB or CD/DVD) in the PC and reboot. Start the installation and you'll be asked if you want to format the pc.
If you have no way of logging in, you will probably have to do a hard-reset (switch the power off/on), but otherwise, you don't need any user rights in Windows to reinstall a computer. This works for Windows, Linux or any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Well actualy to install linux you will  format from low level

Just download a Live CD and will guide you to reach your target.

Now. if your BIOS is locked or something will be more complicated, try first by removing its batery.

To format windows partition you will need shutdown windows normaly. sometimes windows will lock your hdd

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format Windows to gain access to the machine. There's a bug in Windows that allow you to easily do it

If you're stuck on the BIOS, do the step 1. If you're not, go to 2.

1 - Remove the CMOS battery, wait about 20 seconds and put it again. It will restore the BIOS settings to default.

2 - Boot up your pc with any Linux distro that allow you to 'test' it without installing (ubuntu 12.10, for example) and go to this option.

3 - Access the hard drive and go to C:\Windows\System32. Make a copy of cmd.exe file. Then, replace the copy's name with: sethc.exe and overwrite the original file.

4 - Now, boot normally using the HDD. When you get to the Windows login screen, press Shift 5 times. It will 'call' the sethc file and you'll see the command prompt.

5 - Type:

control userpasswords2 (Win XP)

netplwiz (Win 7, 8, 8.1...)

At this point, you can switch the administrator password. Or, if you want, type explorer.exe and be happy!

Comment: This is not a bug. It's you taking action to achieve that effect. Bugs are by definition unintentional and unwanted. Your instructions intentionally introduce a wanted security flaw. Btw, OP probably means BIOS password, because if he could boot Linux he wouldn't have any problems installing it.